# React rendering arrays like spans?

Tags: reactjs

I got this inside a component `render` function return statement:

```
<div className="well">
   {this.props.someArray}
</div>
```

Let's say `someArray = [1,2]`, what I've noticed is React is actually rendering each of the element tags like `<span>` elements. I thought I was going to get an error.

Is this recommended? Are there any guidelines as to what React does when you pass a raw data structure? I haven't seen any material on this.

Comment: You can also render it in another way like `this.props.items.map((item,i) => { return <li key={i}>{item}</li>})` What is the problem?

Comment: Im not sure on the correct structure exactly, but why not create a foreach loop and have each item nested in a `li` or `p` tag?

Answer (score 2):

When React encounters an element that's an array, it renders each element in that array. How it handles each element depends on what it is:

- React components are rendered using their `render()` method.
- `Strings` are wrapped in `<span>` tags (due to funny behavior of text nodes in the DOM, I believe)
- A nested array is flattened (ie: `[1,2,[3,4]]` is treated like `[1,2,3,4]`)
- Other primitive types are converted to strings using `.toString()` and then treated as above.
- Other types will cause an error

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But you can see the behavior here: http://jsbin.com/dofoni/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: In v15 elements of arrays of strings in JSX are now rendered as `<!--react-text:some_id-->text<!--/react-text-->` instead of spans so make sure you update if you are relying on the feature. They should have console.logged a warning for that.